# Using alias in sql to compute other value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this query. I want to perform addition on Total1 and Total2 which are aliases. My query is not working  mysql is showing Unknown column error.

```
SELECT p.Quantity*p.Price AS Total1,
       p.Quantity+p.Tax AS Total2,
       p.Total1+p.Total2 AS Total
FROM p
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't reuse aliases in your `select` clause

```
SELECT p.Quantity*p.Price AS Total1,
       p.Quantity+p.Tax AS Total2,
       p.Quantity*p.Price + p.Quantity+p.Tax AS Total 
FROM p 
ORDER BY id
```

Only in group, having, order clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are evaluated at the very end during the lifecylce of a select statement. These are normally for output purposes only and are not usable for computation

The Sequence of a select statement Evaluation is: 
1. From 
2. Where 
3. Order / grouping 
4. Select ( fields and allias)